# Is there in Javascript a possibility to find the value of the Timer

Tags: javascript

I want to make a timer which starts with program and than if it goes to 5 or to 3 or to zero to make another action

can I do anything like

```
if (document.getElementById('timer').time.value == 0){
    alert("It is over")?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whooa. You are doing this way wrong. First off, you need an actual timer and check inside what the value is at using a variable.

```
var value = 30;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (value === 5) {
         // do something
    } else if (value === 3) {
         // do something
    } else if (value === 0) {
        alert("Over");
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    value--;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Except you din't clear the interval so it isn't really over at `alert("Over");`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `setTimeout()` function, which runs a callback in the event loop after a specified number of milliseconds.